# how to switch between multiple projects and run them in pycharm?

Tags: django, pycharm, multiple-projects

I am thinking of swiching to pycharm for development. Hence I am experimenting with its functionalists. I have three projects opened (two of them are Django -projects). I am unable to switch the projects for execution. Only one project shows up for running.

I have read these links for [opening multiple projects](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/opening-multiple-projects.html) and [switching between projects](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/switching-between-projects.html). But I do not find any link on how to choose which projects to run.

Here is my screenshot. I have three projects in current window. But when I click the run green-icon on top right corner, I see only one project listed. I would like to have other projects opened in the current window to show up, so that I can choose the one I want to run.

[image]

btw, I have `pycharm professional edition` installed.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add a django sever for every project opened, here is how:

[image]

- A good practice to disconnect from running server whenever you are
  going to run another, or you could check the -single instance only-
  checkbox from the same setting window.
- If you got any errors related to project settings, its probably due to one project shared the other project setting file, so you should double check the environment variable from the same setting window to assure every project is using its own settings.py file.

Comment: Feedback, will be helpful(+ve or -ve)

Answer (score 0):

If you go into Edit Configurations under run (or the in the drop down shown above) you can set up run/debug configurations for each of your projects.

Comment: that did not help. I tried. I want all the projects to be listed on dropdown, but it is currently showing only one

Comment: Complete shot in the dark here, but try going to file menu and selecting mark directory as. Choose source root for each directory that you want to add. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is right click on the specific file or project in your project explorer and click run. Once you have done this it will be added to the drop down of items next to the run/debug buttons.

You don't need to add a new django server unless you specifically need one.